# Deleting element in row of 2D Vector - With Iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, 2d-vector

I have 7x20 2D Vector of an "Entry" object. The Entry object has an ID. I want to iterate through my vector and do:

```
if( idToDelete == entry.getID() )
    //Delete entry
```

Currently the code looks like this:

```
for(auto day : entryRegister)
{
    for(auto entry : day)
    {
        if(entryID == entry.getID())
        {
            //Delete Entry
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure how to formulate the expression to actually delete an item. I've tried doing `entryRegister[day].erase(entry)` but I get an error because there is no operator found that takes an iterator in the square brackets.

I saw the request for the declaration of EntryRegister. The relevant information is just that it is declared like this: `vector< vector<Entry> >` and has 7 colums, each with a maximum of 20 rows.

getID returns an unsigned char that is some value between 1 and 70.

This is part of a function where I pass in an ID that i wish to delete. I then iterate through the register, and delete any entry with that ID.

Comment: Let us see the declaration of `entryRegister` and `day`. And the same as you `getID()`, can't you write your own function behind to `deleteID()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not have a function "delete a value" in a vector, since it can be done in two more fundamental steps, commonly known as the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom#Example):

1. Find all items in the vector equal to the value, and swap them to the end of the vector, using [`std::remove` or `remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)
2. Resize the vector to delete those found items, using [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Note that `erase` takes one or two iterators. It only supports erasing items where you already knew the position.

```
for (auto& day : entryRegister) {
    auto erase_begin = std::remove_if(
                day.begin(),
                day.end(),
                [=](const Entry& entry) { return entry.EntryID() == entryID; }
    );
    day.erase(erase_begin, day.end());
}
```

Note that I changed the `entryRegister` loop to get `day` by reference, so the changes actually affect the real day instead of a copy.